How to convert pandas dataframe to json for mlflow serving inference
I am trying to run an mlflow model with Docker. The expected format seems to be:

{"inputs":{"dayofyear":[1,2,3], "hour":[1,2,3],
"dayofweek":[1,2,3], "quarter":[1,2,3], "month":[1,2,3],
"year":[1,2,3]}}

Which works when I curl data like this. However, none of the permutations of pd.DataFrame.to_json() that I've tried give an output that fits this. For example:
df.to_json()

Groups by index (datetime, in this case):
'{"dayofyear":{"1419987600000":365,"1419991200000":365,"1419994800000":365,"1419998400000":365,"14200'

So, my question is twofold:

Is there a native way to group by feature: list?
Is there a clean way to wrap it all in {"inputs":...}? Or do just go with string manipulation?

